# Find the frequency of a sine wave from its angle

Tags: signal-processing

I know I'm doing something stupid but I just can't find out where.
Suppose that I have a sine wave whose angular frequency varies linearly with time. So:

$\omega = ct$

And the sine wave would be:

$S=sin(\omega t) =sin(ct^2)$

Now suppose I have $S$ and I would like to find its angular frequency. For that, I believe I should differentiate the angle of the sinusoid, which gives

$\omega=\frac{d}{dt}ct^2 = 2ct$

and this is twice the value I started with

$\omega = ct$

Where did the "2" come from?!

Comment: If you know "*the angle of the sinusoid*" $\,f(t) = ct^2\,$ then you know $\,c = f(t) / t^2\,$ and $\,\omega=f(t)/t\,$. If you don't know $\,f(t)\,$ then what exactly is it that you know?

Comment: I know the angle, but shouldn't $\omega$ be the time derivative of the angle? If you differentiate the angle, you will get $\omega=2ct$

Comment: "*shouldn't ω be the time derivative of the angle*" $\;-\;$ Only if $\,\omega\,$ is constant, which in your case it's not. Otherwise $\displaystyle \frac{d\left(\omega \cdot t\right)}{dt}= \frac{d \omega}{dt} \cdot t + \omega \cdot \frac{d t}{d t}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are using $\omega$ in two different ways.  There is no relation between the $\omega$ in the first and second equations and the $\omega$ in the third.  The $\omega$ in the third is the instantaneous rate of increase of the angle.  It is, in fact, twice the $\omega$ of the first two equations, as you have shown.  Give it a new name and the problem disappears.

Comment: Thanks. The question becomes why is the rate of increase of the angle twice $\omega$?

Comment: It is the same as a parabola.  It has nothing to do with the fact that it is an angle.  The slope of the parabola $y=x^2$ is $y'=2x$, just as here.